# Bitmap, nullpointer exception

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap

I am trying to write program that transforms a picture to black-white picture. I encountered with a problem and searched for the same issues but i didn't find a proper solution for me. Here is the **code**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageView image;
Drawable drawable;
Bitmap bitmap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap(); **// Here is line that error occur**

    image.setImageBitmap(converter(bitmap));

}

public Bitmap converter(Bitmap first) {
     Bitmap end = Bitmap.createBitmap(first.getWidth(),
             first.getHeight(),
             first.getConfig());
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.graphics.Bitmap android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.getBitmap()' on a null object reference
                      at com.example.murat.giveeffect.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
```

Comment: Does your imageView has an image already loaded?.

Comment: Yes, it isnt empty

Comment: Try this `image.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true); bitmap = image.getDrawingCache();` instead `bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();`

Answer (score 1):

You set your ImageView's bitmap drawable to a `background` attribute

```
android:background="@drawable/clip"
```

instead of `src`.

So change your resource file (activity_main.xml) by replacing background attribute to `android:src`:

```
android:src="@drawable/clip"
```